# get first object from result array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have view file on my app there is code array I want to get first object of that array without going in loop.

```
    <?php
$result = array_chunk($products->result_array(), 3);

foreach($result as $products){  ?>
    <table style="width:100% style="page-break-after:always;"   >

    <tr>

    <?php 
    foreach($products as $productArray){
        $product = (object) $productArray;
        echo '<td>';
    ?>

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 210px;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; margin: auto 5px 5px 0; padding: 5px;">
            <div class="box-header">
                <p class="box-title"><FONT SIZE=12><?php echo $product->product_name; ?></FONT></p>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 100px; text-align: center;">
                <?php echo '<img src="'.'uploads/'. $product->photo.'" class="img-responsive" style="height:100px !important; width: 150px !important"  />'; ?>
            </div>

            <div style="clear: both"></div>
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th><FONT SIZE=12>ID</FONT></th>
                    <td><FONT SIZE=14><?php echo $product->product_id; ?></FONT></td>
                </tr>
```

$result is array of object I'm getting from a form. In below you can clearly see I'm chunking it to 3 more array and looping though individual objects and getting their details to html for example.

```
 <tr>
                    <th><FONT SIZE=12>ID</FONT></th>
                    <td><FONT SIZE=14><?php echo $product->product_id; ?></FONT></td>
                </tr>
```

I want to get the first object details let's say want get $product->product_name of first object of result array without going in loop how to achieve that.

[image: here is the view file result.]

here is complete view file code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="bg-black">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php if(isset($title)) echo $title.' | '; ?>  Sales agent management software (SAMS) </title>

    <style>
        body{
            font-size: 9px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        th,td,p,div,table,h3{margin:0;padding:0}

        @page { margin: 20px; }

        .header{
            border-bottom: 0px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed; top: 0;
        }
        .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0px; text-align: center }
        .pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }

    </style>
</head>

<body>




   <?php
    $usd = get_option('lkr_per_usd', 134);
    ?>



<div class="footer">

Page: <span class="pagenum"></span>, creation time : <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') ?>, create by: <?php echo user_full_name(singleDbTableRow(loggedInUserData()['user_id'])); ?>, $ Rate : Rs. <?php echo $usd; ?> </div>


<br />
<div class="box-body">

    <?php
    $usd = get_option('lkr_per_usd', 134);
    ?>


    <?php
    $result = array_chunk($products->result_array(), 3);

    foreach($result as $products){  ?>
        <table style="width:100% style="page-break-after:always;"   >

        <tr>

        <?php 
        foreach($products as $productArray){
            $product = (object) $productArray;
            echo '<td>';
        ?>

        <div style="width: 100%; height: 210px;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; margin: auto 5px 5px 0; padding: 5px;">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <p class="box-title"><FONT SIZE=12><?php echo $product->product_name; ?></FONT></p>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100px; text-align: center;">
                    <?php echo '<img src="'.'uploads/'. $product->photo.'" class="img-responsive" style="height:100px !important; width: 150px !important"  />'; ?>
                </div>

                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <table class="table table-responsive">
                    <tr>
                        <th><FONT SIZE=12>ID</FONT></th>
                        <td><FONT SIZE=14><?php echo $product->product_id; ?></FONT></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><FONT SIZE=12>LKR</FONT></th>
                        <td><FONT SIZE=14><?php $lkr = get_selling_price($product);
                            echo  number_format(round($lkr, get_option('round_precision')) ); ?></FONT>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> <FONT SIZE=12>US $</FONT></th>
                        <td><FONT SIZE=14><?php echo number_format(round(lkr_to_usd($lkr), get_option('round_precision')) ); ?></FONT></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                        <?php $GLOBALS['a']= $product->product_id; ?>
        </div>

            </td>
        <?php } ?>

    </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </table>
</div><!-- /.box-body -->


</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***Coding in view is completely wrong***

Comment: @Abdulla it's okey.. i added half of code..

Comment: yes Abdulla is right. u should keap your view away of php codes. like `$result = array_chunk($products->result_array(), 3);` And u should use only `if`, `for` , `echo`

Comment: @imsiso please check now complete view file.

Comment: Also i think u need to check your opening and closing tags like `<tr>` and `</tr>` or `<td>` and `</td>`

Comment: the coding. is working fine for now.. i need get single object details for use as header for generating pdf file. basically its pdf file view. it's displaying 3*4 products per page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok man as i said u need to change your way of writing codes but about your specific question use this:

```
$result = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
reset($array);
$first = current($array);
```

you can check this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

---

But still about your way of coding. u should soon go to MVC or such ways of programming so u should separate your view and coding logics

like u may have a page like `view_profile.php` which is going to show user's information. in regular coding u have this:

view_profile.php:

```
<?php session_start();

// you check sessions to see if the user is logged in and has the right to view this page.
// like:

if ($_SESSIONS['is_user_logged_in']){
   $username=$_SESSIONS['username'];
   $name=$_SESSIONS['name'];
   // ....
}else{
    header('location: ./login.php');// if user is not authenticated u redirect to login page
    exit();// prevents the rest of codes to be shown and executed 
}
?>
<html>
<head>

<title>View <?php echo $name; ?>'s profile</title>

</head>
<body>
   <div>Name: <span><?echo $name; ?></span></div>
   ......
</body>

</html>
```

But in a better way u can do it like this:

you have files like

'view_profile.htm' // holds the HTML
'view_profile.php // holds the PHP logic
'inc.php' // holds some useful functions that help you in writing PHP logic

view_profile.htm

```
<html>
<head>

<title>View <?php echo $name; ?>'s profile</title>

</head>
<body>
   <div>Name: <span><?echo $name; ?></span></div>
   ......
</body>

</html>
```

inc.php

```
<?php

function ses_start(){
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
   }
}

function ses_get($key){
    ses_start();
    if(!empty($_SESSION[$key])){
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }
    return NULL;
}

function ses_set($key,$val){
    $_SESSION[$key]=$val;
}

function is_user_loggedin(){
    ses_start();
    if(!empty(ses_get('is_user_loggedin')){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function go($to){
    header('location: '.$to);
    exit();
}

//and lots of useful functions that help u connect and work with data base.
```

view_profile.php

```
<?php 

include('inc.php');

if(is_user_loggedin(){
    $username=ses_get('username');
    $name=ses_get('name');
    //...
}else{
    go('login.php);
}

include('view_profile.html); // and u call the .htm file that holds the HTML the view file)

?>
```

this was a simple sample of separating codes logic(php codes) from views(html tags)

and also u may search about MVC Model-View-Controller and try working with simple MVC frameworks.

Comment: your welcome but as a friend i advice you to check the rest of the answer and also the links. cause u will see that you need to separate your logic and view.  - good luck